# No such found container error at Jenkins job even I was able to list the containers

Tags: docker, jenkins, containers

I get "No such container error" at Jenkins even I was able to list containers before executing the command.

Here is the command that I executed for verifying.  Maybe I am doing something wrong at my docker build command

```
docker run -d --rm --name $containerName -v **$workSpace/target:/build $imageName**
```

Whole Command:

```
ansiColor('xterm') {
            def containerName = "dcktest" + (dockerContainerNumber + 1)
            sh "docker container ls"
            sh "docker run -d --rm --name $containerName -v $workSpace/target:/build $imageName"
            sh "docker container ls"
            try {
                sh "docker exec -t $containerName /bin/bash      \"/build/target/scripts/dockertest.sh\""
            } finally {
                sh "docker stop $containerName"
            }
        }
    }
```

The result in the Jenkins pipeline is :

[image]

Thank you for helps

Comment: You should consider the Jenkins Pipeline Docker plugin for managing Docker within a pipeline: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/

Comment: My hunch is that your Docker container exits after roughly two seconds. When your `docker machine ls` runs, it is still starting up, only to be gone (due to the `--rm`) when it finishes starting, round about the moment that you try to run the `docker exec ...`.

Could you remove the `--rm` and add `docker container ls -a` to your `finally` block? I'm guessing that that will show an Exited status.